# Are there any advantages of scaling horizontal over vertical if resource size is the same?

Tags: node.js, performance, cloud, scalability

I'm using DigitalOcean for hosting my application/s. As it's the same at all of other cloud hosting providers too, there are several options while purchasing a server for your applications. The server can be a very performant one or a weak one depending on your budget and needs. Budget issue aside, I wonder if there is a difference between 4 x 1CPU server and 1 x 4CPU server.

For instance, I have 4 servers for my node.js application, 1 for load balancer (nginx) and 1 for db (redis). Currently each of my node servers has 4 cores. So I have total of 4 x 4CPU computing power.

Well, what if I scale vertically 2 of them and shutdown the other two? Which means: 2 x 8CPU ? The server cost will not change. But I will be deploying my application to 2 servers and I will need to maintain 2 servers instead of 4.

What are the advantages or disadvantages doing so?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will find any definitive rules, although you will probably find plenty of strong opinions.

Given that all your 'servers' are VM's on a cloud providers host servers, in very simple terms the computing power should be the same so long as you have the same RAM, IO etc.

An obvious thing to say at this point is that you should test it and see, but even there you have to be careful as many things can (and will most likely) change over time without you having any visibility, and these might change the results of any tests. For example, the cloud provider may change the host hardware or software; the other VM's on your host machines may change or their load may increase or decrease;

A subtle (and interesting) thing with VM's is that, depending on how the cloud provider has set up their hosts, smaller VM's may have a greater chance of running on a given physical host because they require less resource. In simply terms a 4 core VM can run as soon as their are any 4 cores on the host free, but an 8 core one must wait until there are 8 free. If a given host is more likely to more frequently have 4 free than 8 then the smaller VM *may* get more run time. However, the VM scheduling and the rules for sharing any spare capacity on a host may counter this.

It is also worth thinking about scaling granularity - I think this may actually be the more important factor in your particular case. If you are likely to save expenditure by being able to scale up or down one of your 4 servers for certain periods, then you would lose the ability to do this if you move to just 2 servers.

Balancing this scaling granularity against the reduced maintenance of a smaller number of servers that you have identified may be the key factor for your particular decision.

As a final aside, some would argue that if you can make your servers simple atoms or block box 'building blocks' which are auto built and deployed then your management of them is greatly simplified and you can spin them up and down simply - this effectively lowers the maintenance overhead of multiple servers and may make the greater scaling granularity approach more attractive.

Comment: Actually, I'm deeply interested in Docker and container technologies. Chances are container technology will change the game of scaling.